# std::thread release from inside thread function

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

A typical worker thread is this:

```
std::thread t([](){

  ....
 });
t.join();
```

Is there a way to detach the thread (therefore `join` should return) from inside the thread function? So the thread is "detached"  and code after `t.join()` continues to run, and the thread function also continues to run.

I could do it in Windows with SetEvent but I'm looking for a standard solution.

Comment: The usual way is to just call `t.detach()` instead of `t.join()`.  If you really want to, you could create another thread within the thread and detach that and have the intermediate thread exit...

Comment: Why not just call `detach` instead of `join`?  Also, calling `join` after `detach` will throw an exception

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. Typically threads should never be detached and definitely they should not try to "escape" from parent thread.

Comment: @NathanOliver because I don't want the thread to exit at once, but complete few tasks, then release the wait lock. I could do it also with conditional variables.

Comment: @VTT not at all, there are many non-beginner scenarios where the thread should detach, there are a lot of functions in Windows that allow such stuff.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis There is only one scenario - invocation of some legacy / third party indefinitely blocking function. In this case detach would be a better alternative to, say, allocating thread on the heap and then leaking it. And such a case definitely marks code as problematic.

Comment: Then why not put the code you want to wait on in the main thread, and the stuff you don't care about into a detached thread?  If you don't want to break it up then you could use a "multi-level" thread where you do the work you want to wait on, and before you return, spin up a thread and detach it for the work you don't want to wait on.  Then you can call `join`, it will wait, and then both threads can proceed.

Comment: As a workaround, you can start another thread from your thread and detach from it.

Comment: Note that `join()` doesn't simply return when called on a detached thread object. It will fail, throwing an exception. This all sounds to me like you're looking for an [`std::experimental::latch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/latch) or [`std::experimental::barrier`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/barrier)!? Unfortunately, we don't have those…yet…

Comment: Calling `t.detach()` or `t.join()` always should be the responsibility of whatever function created thread `t`.

Answer (score 0):

#### How to do this

The function the thread runs needs to have a reference to the thread. If it has a reference to the thread, then it can just call `detach` on that reference.

There are two ways to do this with lambdas.

**Capture the thread by reference.** We can have the lambda passed to the thread capture the thread itself by reference:

```
std::thread myThread([&]() {
    myThread.detach(); 
});
```

**Pass the thread to the lambda as an input.**

We can pass references to a function we use to start a thread like so:

```
auto myFunc = [](std::thread& myThread) {
    myThread.detach(); 
};

// Pass a reference to yourself:
std::thread t(myFunc, std::ref(t));
```

Here, we passa a reference to the thread to `myFunc`, and it detaches the thread once it starts. We have to use `std::ref`, which comes from `<utility>`, because threads make a copy of the arguments used to start them *unless* those arguments are passed as a reference_wrapper.

#### Using `std::shared_ptr` to prevent the thread object from falling out of scope before `detach` is called

These methods will only work if `myThread` is still in scope by the time the thread finally executes. If `myThread` has fallen out of scope, this will invalidate the reference and will probably cause the program to crash.

I recommend using something like a `shared_ptr` to get around this:

```
auto myFunc = [](std::shared_ptr<std::thread> myThread) {
    myThread->detach(); 
};

std::shared_ptr<std::thread> t_ptr(new std::thread(myFunc, t_ptr));
```